# How do I install a python module in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-3.5

I am a beginner and read somewhere that we should always create virtual environments when working with Python. Therefore, I created a virtual environment using:

```
python -m virtualenv headlines
```

It copies all files with messages like

```
Using base prefix 'C:\\Program Files\\Python 3.5'
New python executable in C:\Users\Babu\headlines\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
```

Now, I want to install a module locally in this virtual environment using the following command:

```
python -m pip install feedparser
```

I think it is being installed in the Program Files Directory in Python 3.5 folder because the console shows:

```
 copying build\lib\feedparser.py -> c:\program files\python 3.5\Lib\site-packages
error: could not create 'c:\program files\python 3.5\Lib\site-packages\feedparser.py': Permission denied
```

How can I resolve that?

Comment: Read a [tutorial on `virtualenv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). You need to activate the virtual environment before installing the module.

Comment: I suggest you to use Anaconda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have already virtual environment folder successfully created.

First of all, you should be "inside" in your virtualenv in order to use it, thus for linux environments:

```
~$ source ${your_venv_folder_name}/bin/activate
```

will cause command line look like this

```
(venv)~$
```

Or for windows environments, like this:

```
python -m venv ${your_venv_folder_name}
```

According to this [manual](https://zignar.net/2012/06/17/install-python-on-windows/)

> python 3.4
>
> If Python 3.4 is installed it is not necessary to install virtualenv
>   separately. Instead it is possible to use the venv module:
>
> python < 3.4
>
> virtualenv can be installed using the previously installed pip:
>
> pip.exe install virtualenv

Now I see that you haven't enough permissions to install additional modules, so try to restart cmd terminal with administrator privileges according to [this](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl59Kqj-TNAhXJBSwKHWepCSUQFggfMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc947813(v%3Dws.10).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHzfaMpnqPQ2CbtblqAGz0ota9qZw) manual

Now then, with venv activated in current console and have sufficient privileges, it's should be easy to install modules from pip as usual.

Comment: Thanks. just one more question. Why do I need to write like `python -m pip install feedparser` when most tutorials just write `python -m pip install feedparser`?

Comment: What? Two strings the same.

I think, you meant pip install <module> instead of

Comment: I think, you meant 
// > pip install <module> //
instead of
// > python -m pip install <module> //

In the python folder located in C:\>Python27 there are some executables (like pip.exe) which is the cmd programs, so you would invoke it like the first example. Second way is the same, but instead of pip .exe file you use python executable file .py

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. :)