# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfkit'

Tags: python, pdfkit

I installed pdfkit on my virtual environment and when I am trying to use it I am getting this error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfkit'

I installed without venv and every think was ok, so what should I do to make it working on venv.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269686/22305606

Comment: You may also need to select your interpreter in your IDE, if you have multiple environments.

Comment: you need to install it inside of the virtual invironment...